# Physics not working as expected

Tags: python, physics

I want to drop an element on a plane. Here you can see what happens:

[image]

This is my blender file: https://easyupload.io/bh6k7d

I load the object in my python script and set it as a rigid body:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
plane = bpy.data.objects['Plane']

bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=path)
obj.data = bpy.context.object.data
bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.context.object)
scene.rigidbody_world.group.objects.link(obj)
```

The plane is set to rigid body passive.

I want the object to really fall onto the plane. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @batFINGER yes. I let it drop and render images. But the object never really falls onto the plane.

Comment: Have you checked the rigid bodies' margins and collide/interaction type? It looks like it is being calculated as a low poly object.

Comment: What is going here? The script in blend is about rendering PNG? Written lines of script here are part of something? Anyway for physics you need to have origin at centre of object and as Nate_Sycro27 wrote -care about Collision Shape, should be minimal a Convex_Hull if not a Mesh type to act properly.

Comment: you might want to try setting the origin of the object to the center of volume. I am pretty sure blender's physics applies forces to the origin and that can lead to some unexpected behavior if it is outside the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the origin of the object to its center of mass else the simulation will become wonky. 
Select your object.

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

obj.select_set(True)
```

While the object is selected in object mode, right click > Set Origin > To center of mass.

```
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME', center='MEDIAN')
```

Also, Apply scale with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> so that it is uniform at 1,1,1.

```
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)
```

Check the difference here between one cube with its origin to its center of mass and one which is off-center. (the two origins of each cube are the yellow dots) :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can set this with the python api as I am loading the object there?

Comment: I just added that ! If you ever want to know what operator gets called, when you perform an action in blender, open an "Info" workspace somewhere and do your thing using the blender UI. The operators you called will appear in the bottom lines of this workspace

Comment: Thank you for this information! I couldn't find the info-worspace. I am using blender 2.79 and it says `bpy.ops.apply.transformlocrotscale` couldn't be found.

Comment: Actually you don't need this line. Just the other one is sufficient. You can access the info workspace from any window in your blender interface. There is an icon on each of these windows on the top left corner with a downward facing arrow. You can click on it and change the workspace. The "info" is under the "scripting" workspaces

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your suggestion in Blender UI and it works like a charm. The code still won't work for me. I wonder if my object is not selected or something like this. I just added the two lines after my code shown in my question. Any ideas?

Comment: My bad ! You are right, this operator only works with the selected object. You just have to add "obj.select_set(True)" before those lines

Comment: Perfect! I did `obj.select = True` because of my old blender version. Thank you again!